# Wordpress using get_term to retreive slug not working as expected

Tags: php, categories, woocommerce-offtopic, slug, terms

Im using the below code to try and get the slug for the current category and the parent category.

Ive managed to get as far as getting the currently cat slug but the parent displays in readable text and nut slug format.

If anyone can point out where im going wrong and offer any advice i would be very greatful.

Thanks

```
    <?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); 
    $parent = get_term($term->parent, get_query_var('taxonomy') );?>

        <?php echo do_shortcode("[ecs-list-events cat='{$term->slug}']"); ?>   

     <?php 
    echo $term->slug; 
    echo $parent->name;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be completely missing what you want here, but it sounds like you're saying you want the parent category's slug to echo out, rather than the parent category's human readable name.

Rather than this:

```
echo $parent->name;
```

You just need this instead:

```
echo $parent->slug;
```

You can see a [list of the properties here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term#Return_Values) that are returned by the `get_term()` function. You can also always use PHP's [`print_r()` function](http://php.net/print_r) on the term object (so, `print_r( $parent );` in this case) to see all of the properties you have available to you.